# What's my favorite number?

Tags: riddle, cipher

**What is my favorite number?**
You need to find my favorite number from the clues shown below and the hints.

---

I am in cars, but not in buses. 
I have two in cucumbers, and two in clicks. 
I am in computers, but not phones.

---

I am not weird, but I am strange. 
I am in batteries, but not in plugs. 
I am in tables, but not in desks. 
And I am definitely in apples!

---

I have one in cabs and none in storage. 
And two of me are in barbers too.

---

One in Google, but none in Bing. 
One in eating, but none in drinking.

Hint 1:

> The number is a multiple of 625.

Hint 2:

> Try to treat the parts as separate riddles.

Comment: Would [mathematics] be an appropriate tag, or is this mostly wordplay?

Comment: It's mostly wordplay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is 3125.

Reason:

> In each of the riddles the letters C,A,B,E are clued, in that order and then with the A1Z26 cipher encoding you get the number 3125.

Comment: Fun fact: This *is* actually my favorite number!

Comment: Cool! I think this puzzle could have been made harder and better by excluding the word in.

Comment: If you said I am Google but not Plugs and so on.